# Motivation for some theorems on Jordan Canonical Form

Tags: linear-algebra

In the book "First Course in Linear Algebra" by Bhattacharya-Jain-Naugpal, there is a different view for the development of Jordan basis.

I find it difficult *the proof* of the Theorem 3.3 in the [book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=v9NekVwQdWEC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), p. 184. I will be happy if anyone provides motivation for the way followed by authors and also for the proof of Theorem 3.2 and 3.3 in above link. When I presented the proof in classroom without motivation (which I didn't found myself), many students didn't attend my class until the end of the theory of Jordan canonical form. Can anybody help me for motivation?

Comment: Perhaps my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221267/prove-that-finite-dimensional-v-is-the-direct-sum-of-its-generalized-eigenspac/1221341#1221341) could help?