# Prove the direct sum of generalized eigenspaces is the whole vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Given a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over an algebraically closed field, let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$ be its eigenvalues, and let $V_{\lambda_i}$ be the generalized eigenspace of $\lambda_i$. The question is to prove $⨁_{i=1}^dV_{λ_i }=V $. The generalized eigenspace is defined as the following,

> $V_{\lambda_i}=\{x:(A-\lambda_i I)^{m(\lambda_i)}x=0\}$ where $m(\lambda_i)$ is the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_i$.

A proof from the textbook is as the following,

> Let $d_i$ = $\dim V_{\lambda_i}. $Suppose $⨁_{i=1}^dV_{λ_i }\neq V $, then $\sum_{i=1}^k d_i<n$. Let $S_i$ be a basis of $V_{λ_i }$ containing $d_i$ linear independent vectors, and extend $(S_1,...,S_k)$ to a basis of $V$ by adding $(n-\sum_{i=1}^k d_i<n)$ linear independent vectors $S'$, then $S=(S_1,...,S_k,S')$ is a basis of $V$.
>
> Note generalized eigenspaces are invariant subspaces, i.e. $AV_{\lambda_i}\subseteq V_{\lambda_i}$, thus every column of $AS_i$ 
>   is still in $V_{\lambda_i}$ and hence a linear combination of columns of $S_i$ for $1\le i\le k$, thus the following holds (NOTE the "*"s could be non-zero elements),
>
> [image]
>
> where $AS_i=SA_i$ for $i=1,...,k$

Then I get lost with the proof. The remaining part is the following,

> [image]

I get the idea that the proof wants to find an eigenvector $x$ s.t. $Sx$ is a linear combination of only vectors in $S'$, then show $Sx$ is an eigenvector of some eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, and hence the contradiction because $Sx$ would be a vector in $V_{\lambda_i}$ that cannot be expressed as a linear combination of $S_i$. However, I don't understand why this proof is true, especially for the highlightened parts.

Comment: "$x = \left[0,\ldots,0,x\right]^T$" certainly isn't good notation :)

Comment: The proof looks fishy to me as well. You can get a *left* eigenvector of $A$ from a *left* eigenvector of $B$, though, using this $\left[0,0,\ldots,0,x\right]$ construction. Not sure if it helps much.

Comment: The answer to a [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221267/prove-that-finite-dimensional-v-is-the-direct-sum-of-its-generalized-eigenspac/1221341#1221341) might be useful.